# How do I hide "Show Sample Cards" in Google Now?

Tags: google-now

It's been months, I really don't need samples anymore.  Is there any way to completely hide the link?  I've checked all the settings and cannot find anything.

Answer (score 0):

From [Google](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2819496?hl=en):

> To see some sample cards from the main Google Now screen, touch `Menu > Settings > Sample cards`. When you’re finished and want to get back to the main Google Now screen, touch `Hide sample cards`.

Comment: That's the part I want to go away.